# Are concrete blocks a cost effective, modern and strong solution to building a house?

Tags: concrete-block

I do many different house designs in SketchUp. With a 500,250,250mm concrete brick I believe I could create the walls for a house for as little as £1,000. Roughly 1k bricks will be needed to create walls for this house. The concrete bricks will have 2 holes which will connect to the bricks below it creating long holes which concrete is poured down. Are there any problems that could be encountered with concrete bricks, or are walls everywhere just cheaper than I expected? Here's a mockup of the house.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm not sure your question is quite a fit for this site.  The scope of this project is too big to really be considered DIY for the average user, and further it's something of a product/service recommendation and something of an opinion question.

Comment: Concrete blocks are often used to build basement walls in the exact manner you describe.

Comment: Are you asking about using block as a form for poured concrete? The question isn't clear.

Comment: You're really going to want some reinforcing rod in that.  Yes I know you're not in an earthquake area. Neither is Washington DC, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get past the appearance, here are some other considerations: 1) cost of installation of blocks, 2) wall insulation, 3) paint, 4) electrical, 5) larger foundation, 6) seismic loading, 7) future changes, 8) thicker walls.

1) Material cost of blocks is just the beginning. You'll need special shapes, (i.e.: lintels, corners, etc.). You'll need mortar, have you ever laid a block? It's difficult and slow. You'll need reinforcing (horizontal and vertical). You'll need grout in the cells to "hold" the reinforcement.

2) You'll need special insulation on the interior or exterior of the wall and then you'll need to cover that insulation with something.

3) Concrete blocks are porous and you'll need to coat the wall with a block filler before painting.

4) Installing anything in the wall like electricity, will be difficult.

5) The weight of the wall is significantly more than a wood frame wall, so the foundation will need to be larger too.

6) Heavy construction is critical in seismic zones and light buildings are critical in high wind zones. Wood framing is easy to add extra reinforcing (plywood), but block construction gets expensive, especially at openings.

7) Any future changes, remodeling, etc is more difficult than wood.

8) Because the walls are thicker, the building needs to be larger to provide the same size rooms as with wood framed walls. So, you'll have a larger "footprint" and thus require more roofing, attic insulation, etc.

...But fire protection may be better...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. You made some points I didn't think about. How tall would the foundation need to be do you think?

Comment: Keep in mind he's in the UK, wood is not much of a building material there.

Comment: @Harper After he picks up and moves the first 100 blocks, he'll be looking for someone else to move the next 900 blocks or he'll go find all the wood framing he'll need...I bet.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, concrete blocks can be a reasonable option for a basement wall but most people don't care for the look of plain concrete blocks as an exterior.

However, they make colored concrete blocks and split-faced concrete block that are used extensively as an exterior for buildings. These are more expensive but quite attractive and much more permanent. Much more attractive than vinyl siding IMHO.

Usually, the interior wall is built of 2x4 studs in finished areas so placement of plumbing and electrical are not a problem. Even in plain concrete block walls we put in masonry boxes and install devices flush.

Good luck on your project!